# SQL Server: Update Statistics vs Alter Index

Tags: sql-server

Are there any advantages or disadvantages to using `"UPDATE STATISTICS (Index name)"` as opposed to `"ALTER INDEX (index name) ON Table name REBUILD"`  to force the statistics to be rebuilt on an Index?

It seems from other answers here and MS documents that both will achieve this.

Comment: See this. http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/rebuilding-indexes-vs-updating-statistics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER INDEX .. REBUILD` will not just rebuild index, but also force update of corresponding statistics. The equivalent statistics update can be achieved by:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS .. WITH FULLSCAN
```

> Are there any advantages or disadvantages to using "**UPDATE STATISTICS**
>   **(Index name)**" as opposed to "ALTER INDEX (index name) ON Table name
>   REBUILD??"

**Disadvantage:** that command results to a sampled update of stats, it means -  less precise stats as the result.

**Advantage:** Cost of statistics update, even with a fullscan, is just a fraction of Index rebuild cost. Therefore, if the goal is only to keep statistic up to day for good query optimizer decisions, index rebuild, especially on large tables, will be over-killing.